# create a valid json file using nlohmann::json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I'm trying to create a valid JSON file that looks like that:

> [    {    "id": 1,    "price": 0,     "qty": 0 }, {   "id": 1,    "price": 1,
>     "qty": 1 }, {   "id": 2,    "price": 2,     "qty": 2 } ]

my current code creates

> {     "id": 1,    "price": 0,     "qty": 0 } {    "id": 1,    "price": 1,     "qty":
>   1 } {     "id": 2,    "price": 2,     "qty": 2 }

this is the code:

```
int main() {
  std::ofstream f;
  f.open("test.json",std::ios_base::trunc |std::ios_base::out);

  for(int i =0 ;i < 100 ; i++)
  {
    json j = {
        {"id",i},
        {"qty",i},
        {"price",i}
    };
    f << j << "\n";
  }
  f.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, you are creating 3 objects and then printing the objects separately to the file. What you want to do is create one array in you json object, add all 3 object to that array then print it to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `json::array`:

```cpp
int main() {
  json result = json::array();
  for (int i =0; i < 100 ; i++) {
    json j = {
        {"id",i},
        {"qty",i},
        {"price",i}
    };
    result.push_back(j);
  }

  {
    std::ofstream f("test.json",std::ios_base::trunc |std::ios_base::out);
    f << result;
  }
  return 0;
}
```